# How to change windows 7 default view for ftp "network drives"?

Tags: windows, view, ftp, default, drive

I've added an FTP connection in Windows 7 by using "Map as Network Drive". This works great. But there is no working posibility to change the default view from "tiles" into e.g. "details". It always switches back to "tiles". After searching, trying and changing registry entries the behaviour didn't changed.
I love this feature but I hate this silly unchangable default view.

Please help me!

Comment: This is done to prevent slow operations on network drives.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this (after switching to `details`):

Tools -> Folder Options -> View -> Apply to Folders

Comment: Sure. No change. Next time I open it there's the stupid tiles view again.